# how to use exsl:node-set from nodejs/node_xslt?

Tags: node.js, xslt, exslt, libxslt

I am trying to use EXSLT node-set function from nodejs via node_xslt module. This is a simple wrapper around the libxslt library that has support for EXSLT as I could get it. Yet any reference to exsl:node-set produces
Thi is how I use it.

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
                    extension-element-prefixes="exsl">

<xsl:variable name="variable">
  <item />
  <item />
</xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="result" select="exsl:node-set($variable)"/>
```

Any this is the error:

xmlXPathCompOpEval: function node-set not found
XPath error : Unregistered function
runtime error: file ./JayDataContextGenerator_OData_V2.xslt line 58 element for-each
Failed to evaluate the 'select' expression.

UPDATE: Bahblah, author of the node_xslt plugin has updated the project in  github, so the above mentioned transformation executes without any further ado.

Comment: This most probably means that whatever XSLT processor is used by nodejs, *doesn't* have support for EXSLT. You may try using other EXSLT functions and if none of them "works" this confirms the above conjecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured it out inspecting xsltproc.c, I had to add the following additions to node_xslt.c

to the top:

```
#include <libexslt/exslt.h>
#include <libexslt/exsltconfig.h>
```

And to line 138, into FUNCTION( transform )

```
exsltRegisterAll();
```

Extend wscript so that:

```
obj.lib = ['xml2', 'xslt', 'exslt']
```

Then I had to rebuild node_xslt with

```
node-waf build
```

After this exsl:node-set() works like charm.