# Easy way to parse xml to html (with angular) from express.js

Tags: javascript, xml, angularjs

I have xml which is generated from Zend, and it has about 600 lines of code, I need to generated html from that xml, I can do that manually, I already found some modules witch convert xml in json in express js. but there is a lot of work to generate whole html with inputs with models, validation and other stuff. Is there any other way to do this, except doing it manually?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use exsl:node-set from nodejs/node\_xslt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592856/how-to-use-exslnode-set-from-nodejs-node-xslt)